# Why should I choose Native or hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native, mobile-development

I want to develop an app for Android and iOS, which I will use camera, contacts, push notifications and maps

I have some knowledge in Android and I have read a bit about react native, but I would like to know that other frameworks are there for development hybrid app or why should I use react native...

Note: English isn't my native language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest benefit of going with React-Native (rather than Xamarin or some other hybrid mobile) is that you can use what you learn here, and take it to the web by using React.JS. You most likely won't re-use code, but it'll be a breeze to setup the web app after making the mobile app.

Also, JS is very easy to work with.